# Find character in string before position PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string, `$data = "Name Email ID DOB, Name Email ID DOB, Name Email ID DOB, etc."` (with actual name, email ID and DOB data)

I want to extract just one of these sets of values from the string based on the ID. So what I want to do is use `strpos(ID)` to get the position of the ID in the string, but then I want to extract a substring that starts at the first comma before the ID, and ends at the first comma after it.

For example, `$data = "John Doe j@d.com 123 1/01/91, Mary Doe m@d.com 124 1/02/82, Jack Doe ja@d.com 125 1/05/67";`. I have `$id = 124;`, so I want to get a substring `$substr = "Mary Doe m@d.com 124 1/02/82";`

What would be the best way of doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be different, you can also use `str_getcsv()` instead of `explode()`:

```
<?php
$data = "John Doe j@d.com 123 1/01/91, Mary Doe m@d.com 124 1/02/82, Jack Doe ja@d.com 125 1/05/67";

$records = str_getcsv($data);

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $fields = str_getcsv($record, ' ');

    if ($fields[4] == 124) {
        echo $record, "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 Mary Doe m@d.com 124 1/02/82
```

Answer (score 5):

I am providing you search algorithm here:

1. Split the original string using comma and get an array of tokens
2. Loop through the array and find the array element with matching ID

Comment: I prefer this solution, to be honest. +1

Comment: You type faster or more concisely than me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, that just matches as many non-comma characters around your ID as possible. A single non-comma character can be matched with `[^,]`.

```
preg_match('/[^,]* '.$id.' [^,]*/', $input, $match);
// your result will be in $match[0]
```

Note that if `$id` can contain other characters than just digits, concatenating it into a regular expression can be dangerous. In that case, use `preg_quote($id, '/')` instead (which will escape any meta-characters).

Answer (score 1):

if you know the first id and the id that you search.

Just `$result = explode("," $data);`

and substract id that you search and the first id.

```
$index = $idSearch - $FirstId;
```

After you take `$result[$index];`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably `explode` (split) the string into an array on comma, then run the array through a `foreach`, exploding each element on spaces and at the same time check the newly created sub array for that particular id.

But, you're probably better off with a different way of storing this data. (like a DB)

Answer (score 0):

use explode() to convert string to array then simply loop through that array and match the id with the array element. I hope this will solve your issue